# Item in listview present in popup is not getting clicked

Tags: android

[image]I have one custom popup with listview  that is wokring fine.. only issue is i am not able to catch that onItemClicked listner of listview.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,null);



        final PopupWindow pWindow = new PopupWindow();
        pWindow.setContentView(layout);
        pWindow.setWidth(500);
        pWindow.setHeight(700);
        pWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        for(int i=0;i<FilterList.size();i++)
        {
            arrayAdapter.add(FilterList.get(i));
        }

        ListView lv_popup = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.list_info);
        lv_popup.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        lv_popup.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                selectedIndex =position;
                fillSpinner();
                pWindow.dismiss();

            }
        });
```

Comment: how you pass data to list adapter

Comment: i have one  ArrayList<String> FilterList ...data se getting displayed over there...only onclikc action is not working

Comment: if every thing work except onclick , remove all code inside OnItemClickListener and put just Toast , to make sure error is here

Comment: tried that also..m breakout is not getting hit

Comment: may be that cause you use this list inside dialog , did you have screen shot of your application

Comment: did you fix the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

why you dont try alert dialog then

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("your title");
                // here put your items list 
                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                     // do what ever you want here
                        System.out.println("************* clicked-item :"+item);

                    }
                });
             // set your custom view 
             // in your case its layout view 
            builder.setView(layout);
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
```

if you want use your code , you may try 
this attribute to your listview

```
android:clickable="true"
```

and add this attributes to all other views in your XML

```
android:focusable="false"

android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

To be Like that

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/YourID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#adb8c2"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" 

   >

</ListView>
```

I hope this work with you

Comment: i want that to be custom.. curve corners + custom color